# PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters Property does not return always the same printer name

Tags: c#, winforms

My development environment is XP, VS2010. In my programm I use on start this code

```
for (i = 0; i <= PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count - 1; i++)
{
    PrinterSettings printer = new PrinterSettings();
    printer.PrinterName = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];

    if (printer.IsValid == true)
    {
        //do some work
    }
}
```

I am curious to know why `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i]` most of the times returns `'\\192.168.20.32\hp9050'` and some times just `'hp9050'`.

Comment: You can inspect what printers the Spooler has references for, with `PrinterSettings.StringCollection printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters;`. There's the chance you have both a local driver and network connection (the Network "version" of the Printer driver). Anyway, `IsValid` will also include a Fax driver, XPS driver, PDF drivers...